# Scroll to div when another div is at the top of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want my page to scroll to a div(#about) once another div(#home-bottom) has reached the top of the page.

At the minute I have this

```
<div id="home" style="padding-bottom">
    <div id="home-bottom" style="padding-top:1000px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="about" style="height:1000px;"></div>
```

With This jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var distance = $('#home-button').offset().top,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top}, 'slow');
        }
    });
});
```

And it works, however once you have reached About You cannot scroll anywhere as you will just scroll instantly back to About???

Comment: And where is you #home-button div located?

Comment: As I see you want to scroll to #about only once? Then just add a flag class on the body when you do your animation. And add a condition, to check if this class is already exists. Eg `if ( !$('body').hasClass('alreadyScrolled') && $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) { $('body').addClass('alreadyScrolled'); /* do your animation */ }`